# Implementing HTML & CSS into Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to make my views.py point to a HTML page I've made that has embedded CSS, is this the best approach? I'm also running Django locally for testing purposes until it is moved to a production server how would I make local links to point to my HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#templates
The default includes app/templates/ to your template paths and i would recommend to store your template files there. 
Static files like .css and .js are served in similiar way
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

The django test server also serves static files like css and js for you.

I would also recommend to move your css in one or more seperate .css files.
It helps you on the long run to keep your project clean.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your views.py should be something like:

`def my_view(request):
return render(request, 'my_html_page.html', {})`

2) You should put '***my_html_page.html***' to folder "***templates/***"

3) You should make folder "***static***" and put there you css file (i.e. styles.css)

4) in "my_html_page.html" you should link your css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="***{% static 'styles.css' %}***" rel="stylesheet">
```

5) you should run command 
    `python manage.py collectstatic`

p.s. on production server you should install whitehoise
    `pip instal whitenoise`